# How to create a block letters form input in libreoffice writer

Tags: forms, libreoffice, writer

I would like to create a document including a input form.
The printed version of the form should have little boxes for block letter input ("monospace font") like this:

[image: block letters input]

The form will be printed and will be filled out manually using pens (but it would be good if the form could also be easily filled out digitally via pdf form)

Is there any convenient way apart from creating separate input boxes, or tables or other quick fixes which do not make it inconvenient filling the form digitally?

One way could be to use a background image with the required block pattern.

Comment: I would go with the image in background.  
Which document you want: Calc or Writer?  
How you would like to fill in the BLZ? By means of a "user prompted" way, or programmatically?

Comment: i updated the question regarding your questions

Answer (score 0):

If you only want it printable - create a document and set the image as background.

If you want a computer fillable form for a SEPA banking transaction form - do a search, as there are free PDF forms available.